# When i export my java as runnable jar file, do not work

Tags: java, eclipse

i have  tried so many times to not post this question by searching my problem solution but i am **failed**,

i am new to java, i am facing a problem,that i want a runnable java application 
and

when i tried to export it into runnable it does not execute. i am using 
Eclipse for java.

My code is

```
package hello;

public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println("Hello World");

   }

}
```

Comment: Try starting it via the command line (java -jar ...) and tell us what the error message is, otherwise people can only guess.

Comment: it shows a string " HELLO WORLD"

Comment: If it does show a string "Hello World" then it does execute and you don't have a problem. In other words... Tell us what your problem is. How are you trying to execute it? How does it not work? Best way to get the error message is starting it via console/terminal/command line.

Comment: Why i can not execute the jar file with **javaw.exe**

Comment: Your program is compiled into Java byte code (.class files). The Java byte code isn't executable on the processor. Java then executes the byte code in a virtual machine (javaw.exe on Windows), available for many operating systems. http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jcarroll/15-100-s05/supps/basics/history.html

Comment: If you export your program to an executable .jar, you have to execute it via java -jar ....

Comment: Your code writes to the console, but **javaw** doesn't open a console window so don't see any output. If you want to write to the console use **java**, otherwise you need to display output in some other way, for instance creating a window.

Comment: how can i create a window @agnul

Answer (score 1):

Since there no code to pause the screen so it may be the case that JAR file is getting executed but you are not able to see the output window. Check it with some pause statement. May be you can use Thread.sleep(x) for wait.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 3 ways to *execute*  a JAR:

1. **double-click** on it, obviously Java must be (correctly) installed and the system support double-clicking (has a mouse and a graphical interface, e.g. Windows) - this does not open a console and you would not see any output going to System.out, like in your code.

   In that case you could add a statement as `JOptionPane.showMessage(null, "Hello World!");` that opens a dialog and shows the given message;
2. **`java -jar <file.jar>`** this executes the jar opening a console - you will see what is going to System.out;
3. **`javaw -jar <file.jar>`** same as above but without console - text written to System.out will be lost! JOptionPane, as explained at point 1, works for this case too (assuming system with graphical interface).